# Дешифрование текстов, зашифрованных при помощи xor

Tags: python, python-3.x, криптография

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить задачу: есть несколько шифротекстов, зашифрованных одним ключом. Как расшифровать данные тексты?
Xor шифротекстов равен xor исходных сообщений, но непонятно, куда двигаться дальше.

```
import os
#исходные
plaintext1 = b'hello world'
plaintext2 = b'supersecret'
# задаем ключ
key = os.urandom(len(plaintext1))
print(key)
# функция шифрования
xor = lambda x, y: bytes(a^b for a, b in zip(x, y))
# шифруем
ciphertext1 = xor(plaintext1, key)
ciphertext2 = xor(plaintext2, key)

# набор всех текстовых символов данной кодировки
textchars = bytes({7,8,9,10,12,13,27} | set(range(0x20, 0x7f)))

# множество всех xor всех пар символов
all_xors = sorted((a^b, (a,b))
    for a in textchars
    for b in textchars)
```

Comment: В чём собственно задача - вам неизвестен ключ и нужно его найти, пользуясь зашифрованными текстами?